# can't change ft_min_word_len in mysql

Tags: mysql, apache, wamp

I have followed all the instructions I could find, and they were all similar and straight forward, yet still the minimum word length does not change, and I don't know what else I can do. Here is what I have done:

a. opened wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\my.ini

b. added the following line under the [mysqld] and [myisamchk] headings:

`ft_min_word_len = 3`

c.clicked restart all services in WAMP

d. ran the following line in mysql console:

`REPAIR TABLE dates QUICK`

e. ran the following code to check if it worked:

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_min_word_len'`

and every time it's still returns 4. Please help! Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically MySQL should pick up the parameters under [mysqld] and then check for more under a section names like its service name [servicename].

So it might be a good idea to try putting `ft_min_word_len = 3` under the `[wampmysqld]` section header instead, as this is what is read by wamps MySQL as the service is called `wampmysqld`.